# PHP returning strange row counts

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, mysql-num-rows

i am working with a very large data set (786,432 rows to be precise).

So, to prevent memory limits I want to loop over the data set in piles of 50,000 rows, so to test this out I thought I would try:

```
function test(){
    $start = 0;
    $end = 50000;

    $q = $this->db->select('uuid')->from('userRegionLink')->limit($end, $start)->get();
    $i = 0;
    while($q->num_rows() != 0){
        echo 'Round: '.++$i.'<br />';
        echo 'Rows: '.$q->num_rows().'<br />';
        echo 'Start: '.$start.'<br />';
        echo 'End: '.$end.'<hr />';

        $start = $end;
        $end = $end+50000;
        $q = $this->db->select('uuid')->from('userRegionLink')->limit($end, $start)->get();
    }
}
```

But my results are very strange: look at round 9 and below.

What is causing this?

> Round: 1
> Rows: 50000
> Start:
>   0
> End: 50000
>
> ---
>
> Round: 2
> Rows:
>   100000
> Start: 50000
> End:
>   100000
>
> ---
>
> Round: 3
> Rows:
>   150000
> Start: 100000
> End:
>   150000
>
> ---
>
> Round: 4
> Rows:
>   200000
> Start: 150000
> End:
>   200000
>
> ---
>
> Round: 5
> Rows:
>   250000
> Start: 200000
> End:
>   250000
>
> ---
>
> Round: 6
> Rows:
>   300000
> Start: 250000
> End:
>   300000
>
> ---
>
> Round: 7
> Rows:
>   350000
> Start: 300000
> End:
>   350000
>
> ---
>
> Round: 8
> Rows:
>   400000
> Start: 350000
> End:
>   400000
>
> ---
>
> Round: 9
> Rows:
>   386432
> Start: 400000
> End:
>   450000
>
> ---
>
> Round: 10
> Rows:
>   336432
> Start: 450000
> End:
>   500000
>
> ---
>
> Round: 11
> Rows:
>   286432
> Start: 500000
> End:
>   550000
>
> ---
>
> Round: 12
> Rows:
>   236432
> Start: 550000
> End:
>   600000
>
> ---
>
> Round: 13
> Rows:
>   186432
> Start: 600000
> End:
>   650000
>
> ---
>
> Round: 14
> Rows:
>   136432
> Start: 650000
> End:
>   700000
>
> ---
>
> Round: 15
> Rows:
>   86432
> Start: 700000
> End:
>   750000
>
> ---
>
> Round: 16
> Rows:
>   36432
> Start: 750000
> End:
>   800000
>
> ---

Comment: Garbage collection? Do you **really** want PHP keeping 800k rows in memory?

Comment: Actually, thats a point, the whole thing is screwy, Rows should be 50,000 for every loop except the last, whats happening here?

Comment: Rows is ***increasing*** by 50k on each iteration, tracking the total rows in the array used by `$q`.  At some point, PHP is deciding to remove some of the array values though.  I'd be interested in whether it's removing them sequentially from the "front" (i.e. FIFO) or if it's doing it in a less deterministic way.  I'm betting the latter :)

Comment: :D logic error on my part, For some reason I had decided that I also needed to increase the limit as well as the offset :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like $end is not a global offset just number of records to fetch (offset from $start). Try to set $end always for 50000 and changing only $start.